# Can I split a custom python library into multiple files?

Tags: python

So I have built a python library in a file, call it `mylib.py`, which I then import in various scripts using `import mylib`. I wish to split `mylib.py` into multiple files, say `mylib1.py` and `mylib2.py`, while still using them as a single library like so: `import mylib` , `mylib.mymethod()`, etc...

Is there any way to do this that is perfectly equivalent to having them in a single file? This means that, for instance, `mylib1` should be able to use methods from `mylib2`.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "proper" way to do this is to create a package, and have the package's `__init__.py` file import the desired symbols. This will assign the imported symbols to the package object.

For example, suppose I have the following file, `my_lib.py`:

```py
def foo():
    print("Hello world, I'm Foo!")

def bar():
    print("Hello world, I'm Bar!")
```

I can split this file into two, `foo_module.py` and `bar_module.py` (containing the "foo" and "bar" functions respectively), then place them in a package `my_lib`:

```
mylib
├── bar_module.py
├── foo_module.py
└── __init__.py
```

A [regular Python package](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) is a directory with an `__init__.py` file in it, in addition to the module files it contains.

Now, as it currently stands, this won't make `import my_lib` act exactly as before. This is because the `foo` and `bar` functions are contained in *submodules* of `my_lib`, so they are only available if you import those *submodules*:

```py
from my_lib import foo_module
from my_lib import bar_module
foo_module.foo()
bar_module.bar()
```

To make them available directly from `my_lib`, we need to modify its `__init__.py` to import those functions:

```py
from my_lib.foo_module import foo
from my_lib.bar_module import bar
```

This imports `foo` and `bar` into `my_lib`'s namespace. From then on, whenever some other code imports `my_lib`, it will be able to directly access `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: Thank you so much that looks like my solution. Small extra question. Say all my modules require pandas. Could I `import pandas` in the `__init__.py` file or will I need to import it in each module separately?

Comment: Essentially, I have `base.py` which is a class. Then I have `a.py` and `b.py` which are subclasses of `base.py` (i.e., in `a.py` I have `def __init__(base)`. I also have `utilities.py` that's a bunch of custom functions (not a class). All of these use a lot of the same libraries. All the classes use `utilities`. How would you structure a package like this?

Comment: You would need to import pandas in each module. Essentially, each module (and package) is its own object. The attributes of that object are the global variables (and functions) that module has, plus any symbols that it imports (which are the same as global variables).

Answer (score 0):

Just put import mylib2 in mylib 1, so when you import mylib1, it can use methods from mylib2.

The main program might not be able to use mylib2 functions, though.

Comment: Yeah, I tried something like this - I did `import one` and `import two` into `lib.py`, then I did `import lib` in `main.py`, and unsurprisingly `main.py` couldn't access the functions defined in `one` and `two` even though (naturally) `lib.py` could.

Comment: what about in `main.py` calling `lib.one.method()`, rather than just `lib.method()`?

Answer (score 0):

In `lib.py`, rather than doing `import one`, you could do `from one import *` (and same with two). Doing this will put all the objects from one into the lib *namespace* (or something like that. That means than inside of lib you wouldn't call `one.func_one()`, but you would just call `func_one()` straight away.

So then, in `main.py` (or whatever you have that you are ultimately using) you could `import lib` and then call `lib.func_one()` even though `func_one()` itself comes from `one.py` and not from `lib.py`.

In main.py you could even do `from lib import *` and you could call everything directly without the `lib.`, but I think that is a bad idea - it is usually nice to see throughout the code where things are coming from and to not clutter up the namespace.

When you do `from xxx import *` you bring in the names of all of those things directly, and you could accidently write over something if two libraries/files have functions or global variables with the same name.